# Using np.where to add column to pandas using self-created function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame with two columns ('no1' & 'no2'), some of the values contain Chinese characters, some do not.

```
no1                     no2
Paul Pogba              贝克汉姆
Gianluigi Buffon        莱奥内尔・梅西
莱奥内尔・梅西           莱奥内尔・梅西
Cristiano Ronaldo       莱奥内尔・梅西
STEVE HARRIS            zinedine zidane
Cristiano Ronaldo       Gianluigi Buffon
```

I would like to add a column which has the value of 1 if either of the two columns has a string with a Chinese character in it, and 0 if neither do. The function looks like this:

```
def find_china_symbols(text):
    counter = 0
    if isinstance(text,str):
        for char in text:
            if ord(char) > 10000:
                counter += 1
        if counter > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Previously I have used `np.where` to create this column (as below) but it doesn't work in this case. Why does it not?

```
df["Chinese"] = np.where(find_china_symbols(df["no1"]) | find_china_symbols(df["no2"]),1,0)
```

Ideally, this would be the result:

```
no1                     no2                  Chinese
Paul Pogba              贝克汉姆              1
Gianluigi Buffon        莱奥内尔・梅西         1
莱奥内尔・梅西           莱奥内尔・梅西         1
Cristiano Ronaldo       莱奥内尔・梅西         1
STEVE HARRIS            zinedine zidane       0
Cristiano Ronaldo       Gianluigi Buffon      0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach it like this with `applymap`

```
def find_china_symbols(text):
  return any(map(lambda char: ord(char) > 1000, text))

df['Chinese'] = df.applymap(find_china_symbols).any(1).astype(int)
```